# Money price tag

Tags: price, zpl

I'm currently developing an label in ZPL for a company wanting to print money/price tags with RFID.

I showed them my first "blueprint" and they said it looks great.
But they have one problem: The price is displayed like "1234,44€" or "1234,00€"
And they say when there are zeros that they want it that it displays "1234,-€"

How is it achievable in ZPL ?
Are there things like conditions, cause I dont think so.

I am unable and sorry that I cant provide my ZPL code, but it's pretty much like this:

```
^FO0,0,0
^FPH
^TB0,0
^A0N,50,45
^FD[PRICE]
^FS
```

Comment: How about providing a simili ZPL code? And about your question, can't you simply pass the correct string to the printer instead of dealing with this in ZPL code?

Comment: The thing is that i dont know what the database of the clients look like...I dont know what they will pass to the price variable. It could be similiar to 1234,- but it also could be 1234,00.

Comment: This is pretty much what i use:
^FO0,0,0^FPH^TB0,0^A0N,50,45^FD[PRICE]^FS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to solve the problem here...

A co-worker and me thought about this and came to the conclusion:
Everything works great and its not our fault when someone inserts a value that they dont like. Its not in our hands cause we cant look trough the database or change prices from "1234,00" to "1234,-"

So, actually i never really had a problem to begin with.
But thanks anyways :)

Comment: Pretty much what I was about to answer you. Don't forget to accept your answer ;)